# Find names using initials - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a customers database and I want to find customers names starting with initial alphabets. Also I want to put an OR condition in between the initials so that I can search from a set of 3 alphabets. SQL query that I could make out so far is mentioned below but it throws an error.

`SELECT * FROM`customers`WHERE first_name IN(LIKE('j%', 'g%', 'k%'))`

Comment: SELECT * FROM customers WHERE first_name like 'j_%'

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar But I want to search using 3 patterns as mentioned above in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some regex.

```
 SELECT * FROM customers WHERE first_name REGEXP  '^(j|g|k).*'
```

For more info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Have a good day!

Comment: No worries, it was a pleasure to help you out. You will benefit a lot from learning a bit of regex.